# How to put unicode characters on a System.Windows.Forms.Button in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unicode, character

In Visual Studio 2008 in a C# WinForms project, there is a button on a form. In the properties view, the property "Font" is set to "Arial Unicode MS".

What do I need to put into the property "Text", so I get the unicode character \u0D15 displayed on the button?

When I put \u0D15 into the "Text" property, the button displays the six characters "\u0D15" instead of one unicode character.

In the following PDF, you can see the unicode character for \u0D15:
http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0D00.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't have to escape your unicode characters in strings as C# is inherently unicode. Just put your unicode characters as they are into the string. For example:

```
button1.Text = "日本";
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to run "charmap" and copypaste from there or copypaste it from elsewhere.

Answer (score -2):

Just try the following in you C# code:

```
button.Text = "0x0D15";
```

Comment: Why concatenate string? you can just say `button.Text = "\x0D15"`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/char