# Ultrabutton not displaying unicode character in text property while running application

Tags: c#, winforms, button, infragistics

I'm trying to display the text property of a UltraButton to this unicode character- ▼ .
I've tried to copy this from the Character Map and also tried something like-

```
button1.Text = "\u2129"
```

The problem is both of them show the arrows in the designer mode in VS, but when I run the application, it shows an unrecognised symbol. I've gone through [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506996/c-sharp-button-text-unicode-characters) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255907/how-to-put-unicode-characters-on-a-system-windows-forms-button-in-c), but the arrows only show up in the designer view, not while running the application. Why is this happening. Also, I've set the Font name to 'Arial Unicode MS'

[image: Buttons in Designer View]

[image: Buttons while running application]

Comment: I tested this with a microsoft button, label and UltraButton and the character displays correctly for me.  Do you also see the same behavior with a Microsoft label?

Comment: it displays correctly for Windows.Forms.Buttons for me, but not the ultrabutton

Comment: I was asking about a Microsoft Label.  My expectation is that it will be the same as the UltraButton.

Comment: Uhm, \u2129 for that Font is a different character. Where do yuo set the Font? In the standard Font property or through the FontData inside the Appearance object?

Comment: Also, did you have changed any other properties on the UltraButton (check with RightClick on button, Custom Property Pages, Modified Only)

Comment: Consider asking on the [Infragistics Forums](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/default.aspx?GroupID=37).

Comment: @Steve: I know that \u2129 is a different character. This was just an example.Sorry for that. I typed in another code which worked in designer as well

Comment: So it works now? Because, as @alhalama said, testing the UltraButton with this \u2129 or other unicode chars works as expected. Thus my request to look for other modified properties.

Comment: Well, none of the other properties were modified, and the change was Not made from the FontData in the Appearance. It was made from Font

Comment: @karan is the behavior specific to that machine or does it happen on other machines as well?  If it happens on other machines, do you have a sample that I can test with that does reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the issue you are experiencing is unique to the UltraButton. From the looks of the image you just posted, you could probably get away with just using a standard Windows From Button. If you can, just open your ClassName.Designer.cs and find where your button text is being set. Copy the actual character into the text string:

```
this.YourButton.Text = "▼";
```

This shows up correctly in both the designer and when running the application.

If you really don't want to use a standard Windows Forms Button, you could always go about converting your text to an image and adding the image to the button. Would look something like this:

```
string text = "▼";
Font font = new Font("Arial Unicode MS", 12f);
Image img = new Bitmap(1, 1);
Graphics drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
SizeF textsize = drawing.MeasureString(text, font);
img.Dispose();
drawing.Dispose();
img = new Bitmap((int) textsize.Width, (int)textsize.Height);
drawing = Graphics.FromImage(img);
drawing.Clear(YourButton.BackColor);
Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
drawing.DrawString(text, font, textBrush, 0, 0);
drawing.Save();
textBrush.Dispose();
drawing.Dispose();

YourButton.Text = "";
YourButton.Image = img;
```

Comment: it's showing up...but the image shows up in one corner of the button. another problem is that it has a white background around it that I don't want.

Comment: You can change the background color of the image you create using drawing.Clear(Color.ChooseAColor). You can also change the text color when you create the new SolidBrush(Color.ChooseAColor). You will only run into problems if your button has a gradient background. As for the image location issue, I would be very surprised if the UltraButton does not expose some property that allows you to change the alignment of your image so it is centered in the button.