# Why does some unicode characters appear as a box in the visual studio property grid?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface, unicode, propertygrid

I can't type in certain special Unicode characters in the properties window for a control in Visual Studio 2017. The magnifying glass character (⌕) appears in the code just fine, but in the design mode for a file and the text property of the property grid for that item, it appears as a black box.

I've looked and googled around but I can't find any specific examples on adjusting this. I'm also not sure how to change the font in Visual Studio's property grid either.

I want to be able to see the magnifying glass, because the control displays the square box at runtime instead of a proper Unicode character.

In the image below – at the text property – you can see it is a black box, even though I typed/copied over the Unicode character. To the left is that control, and it shows the box character instead of a proper magnifying glass character.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put unicode characters on a System.Windows.Forms.Button in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255907/how-to-put-unicode-characters-on-a-system-windows-forms-button-in-c)

Comment: That question and the solutions there did not solve the problems either, and the last comment there was that things didn't work; no solution to follow up there.